# How can I call a variable from a string?

Tags: java

I'm reading the text file:

```
3
H2O
O   -0.0000   -0.0589   -0.0000
H   -0.8110    0.4677    0.0000
H    0.8110    0.4677    0.0000
```

With this I can assemble a 3D model of water.
This file firstly shows which element, then x, y, and z.
Each element will be a different color. I have set up an enum to do that:

```
public enum AtomColors {

// Sign(red, green, blue, alpha);
H(1, 1, 1, 1), He(1, 1, 1, 1), O(1, 1, 1, 1);

private final float red, green, blue, alpha;

    AtomColors(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
    }

}
```

How can I retrieve the color though? The text file only returns a string when I need to access the variable that corresponds to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about [`valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)?

```
AtomColors.valueOf(someStr);
```

Comment: `AtomColors.valueOf(someStr).getColor()`, assuming that `valueOf` returns a valid result, but correct nonetheless (ps- just nit picking ;))

Comment: Wow, that was simple! Thanks for your help!